# Big query sql: month to date query

Tags: sql, date, datetime, google-bigquery

I have daily data and the code im using creates a report between some dates. I want to replace the date interval with month to date. So every time it will generate a month to date report based on which month we are in. Is there a simple way to do it? thanks :)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: date                id                 amount
01-07-2021   123                50
02-07-2021   123                30

now i am using >= TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL 30 day))

but at the end i want to have a month to date report which will include only july for this month

Comment: What are the desired results you want? @Lea123

Comment: I want to get results month to date. So from the beginning of the month we are in to current date. without entering dates manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example using BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  your_table
WHERE
  your_date_field BETWEEN 
    DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), month) --to get start date of current month
    AND 
    CURRENT_DATE()
```

You should be able to use that in a WHERE clause and